# How to build the decision tree in this case?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

In my app, I have `Item`s.

An `Item` has

- a base name (sword, shield etc)
- a rarity (normal, magic, rare, unique)
- up to 6 mods taken from a pool of about 400 (could be reduced, as a lot of them are uncommon or useless). Most mods have values (+**100** to maximum life). The worth of an item greatly depends on those values too, not only the presence of the mod.
- a price

My goal is to input an item and get a price estimation.

Not sure how to build the decision tree for this, especially because of the huge list of mods

I thought about something like that, but that would give an insanely big tree, even after pruning, I think.

[image: tree]

Any pointers on how to build this tree that would allow me to predict an item price?

Comment: Dumb question: have you tried a simple linear regression?

Comment: I haven't, no. Someone suggested decision trees for this problem so I decided to look into it. But I'll try linear regression. It seems suited to the problem too, thanks. If you feel like it, you can add an answer detailing that, and I'll accept it at the end of the bounty if I don't get a good answer for the actual question.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add to your question some 500-1000 items as CSV?

Comment: @carlosdc I'll try to generate one for you, sure.

Comment: @carlosdc Here is the csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FTLwpvNuVVlVg5yxUlLs9ZjFWeBEOZjAEslIojphcf4/edit?usp=sharing Let me know if you need the mods in another format. Thanks!

Comment: @Robin Aren't you making your life way too complicated? What would be wrong about defining the price model mathematically rather than based on data. I would go as simple as: `price = basePrices[baseName] * rarityFactors[rarity] * product(modFactors[mod] for mod in mods)`. You can make such a model as complex as you want (i.e. define fancy transformations from mod to modFactor or make those rarity dependent), but in essence you will have a decent price model without entering hundreds of lines of data, which, unless really complete, is likely to have nasty outcomes in some edge cases

Comment: Like @Oleg, I really wonder why you'd need a decision tree for that. A simple formula like he showed computes a price just fine. Simple, straighforward, efficient ...and it'll take you 10 minutes to do. Moreover, I would even say a decision tree is totally unrelated to your goal, since they are used to classify data. And you don't want to classify 1000 items in 20 price classes, do you?

Comment: @arnaud I thought I did because someone recommended it to me. I didn't know what it was for exactly at the time. Now, I know it's not the right tool.

Comment: @OlegS. The problem is finding this equation, and it won't take 10 minutes as arnaud suggests. I can't just guess the equation though! The game is very complex, and mods on items are valued very differently based on which other mods are on the item, their values etc. That's why I want to just give thousands of data points, and let the regression algorithm come up with the equation for me. I actually used Weka with a very small dataset to test, and it seems like it will work. (ps: I do have a very complete data set, I'm indexing ALL the items that are being sold).

Comment: @Robin If you are indexing _all_ the items then you do not need any prediction, regression or otherwise, you need a map. You only need a prediction if you need a price for a _new_ item, which is similar to some other ones, but not necessarily exactly the same. For this, complete set of all possible combinations of parameters is needed. But really your mods are not defined at all to suggest any sensible approach .

Comment: I'm indexing all the items that are `currently` being sold. So I have a lot of data to learn from. But my goal is to determine the price of new items, so I think I do need a regression model. I don't understand your last sentence, could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, items are generated randomly, no 2 items are the same, except for uniques, but let's not worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. Your problem is defined as **regression** problem, because the value you are estimating is numeric (price). In **classification** problems you are estimating a class of an instance, where there are finite number of classes. Decision trees are used to "decide" which class an instance belongs to, so obvisously are used for classification, so you cannot use it for your problem.

So, now you know your problem is regression, and there are many methods used for regression problems. I suggest you take a look at the following:

- linear regression
- regression trees
- model trees

Their power not only lies in prediction part, but also in relatively easy understanding of the models built. This means you will understand why some Item comes cheap and other expensive by examining the model.

You can find all those methods in machine learning suite named [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). But before using it, you'll have to prepare the data first. This doesn't just mean converting it into right file format, but more importantly, decide how to represent the data. The first two attributes are so-called nominal, and the target attribute is numeric, so in .arff format they should look sth like:

```
@attribute base_name {sword, shield, ... }
@attribute rarity {normal, magic, rare, unique}
@attribute price numeric
```

Now if I undestand the problem correctly, mods are either on or off, so I'd represent them using the following:

```
@attribute mod1 {0,1}
@attribute mod2 {0,1}
...
@attribute mod400 {0,1}
```

This also means, you have to prepare all 400 data, which will moslty be zeros, with up to 6 ones, representing mods being used, turned on, or however you name it.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this. The thing missing about mods is that each mods have values: `+X to maximum life` for instance. The worth of an item varies drastically based on these values, and not only based on the presence of the mod. I guess I could consider `+10 to max life` and `+80 to max life` as 2 completely different mods, but it doesn't seem like a great solution. (btw I probably have a lot less mods than 400, I can ignore a lot of useless or uncommon ones).

Comment: Would just having `@ATTRIBUTE mod1 NUMERIC` work? It would be 0 if the mod doesn't exist, and the value otherwise. Or -1, because some mods do not have values, but their presence is significative.

Comment: I tried with [this sample data](https://gist.github.com/niuage/7f16f937f69f8901634b) in the Weka Experimenter. It created this file [here](https://gist.github.com/niuage/36b9024950df904f2638). Do you know what I need to do in the weka GUI to actually run another set of test data and predict their prices?